# SQL ranking over two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables with user rankings.
Table **rankingA** and **rankingB**.
Each table has the columns:

- user_id
- points
- group_id

Higher the points so higher the rank of the user/group...

Now i try to get the group ranking for the question which rank has my group.
So far i have this SQL:

```
select sum(ra.points) as rapoints, sum(rb.points) as rbpoints from public.rankinga ra
LEFT JOIN public.rankingb rb ON ra.group_id=rb.group_id and ra.user_id=rb.user_id where
ra.group_id=200;
```

It returns the points from rankinga and rankinb for the group 200.
**How can i get the rankings of the group?** I tryd it with:
row_number() OVER (ORDER BY sum(rb.points) DESC) AS rankb
but got a wrong result.

My expected result for group_id 200 is:

```
rapoints,rbpoints,rarank, rbrank
420,        10,     3,  same points as group_id 300 so rbrank 2 or 3
```

How can i get this?

#### Setup

```
CREATE TABLE rankinga
(
user_id bigint,
group_id bigint,
points integer
)
CREATE TABLE rankingb
(
user_id bigint,
group_id bigint,
points integer
)
insert into public.rankinga (user_id,group_id,points) values (1,100,120),(2,100,300),  (3,100,20),(4,200,300),(5,200,120),(6,300,600);
insert into public.rankingb (user_id,group_id,points) values (1,100,5),(2,100,3),(3,100,10),(4,200,2),(5,200,8),(6,300,10);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do this with `union all`, aggregation, and the window function.  Joining the tables is likely to miss rows (if users are in one table but not the other) or over count (if you join on group).  So this may do what you want:

```
select group_id, sum(rapoints) as rapoints, sum(rbpoints) as rbpoints,
       sum(rapoints) + sum(rbpoints) as points,
       dense_rank() over (order by sum(rapoints) + sum(rbpoints) desc) as ranking
from ((select ra.group_id, sum(ra.points) as rapoints, 0 as rbpoints
       from public.rankinga ra
       group by ra.group_id
      ) union all
      (select rb.group_id, 0, sum(rb.points) as rbpoints
       from public.rankingb rb
       group by rb.group_id
      )
     ) ab
group by group_id;
```

If you want to select just one group, then put this in a subquery (or CTE) and then select the group.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/142f5/1) is a SQL Fiddle.

EDIT:

If you want just the result for one group, you still need to calculate the values for all groups.  So:

```
select ab.*
from (<above query here>) ab
where group_id = 200;
```

Comment: But how can i filter by group_id=200 and get the right result? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/142f5/3